# Undetailed error in Editor or Editor Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So....I've spent the whole day trying to get vs to work!!

Whenever I try to create new project or save any file I get unexplained error message telling me to find details in

`C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml`

And here is what I got there:

[image]

I use vs community edition and I have tried the following:

- Repairing visual studio...[no luck]
- Uninstall community edition and Install Express edition....[no luck]
- Uninstall express and then install community edition again....[no luck]

And the error persists in all above attempts....

Any idea will be greatly appreciated..

Update:

when I try to save any file I got also the following error in that `xml` file:

> The color 'Popup' in category 'de7b1121-99a4-4708-aedf-15f40c9b332f' does not exist.

Comment: I'm getting this same error.  Any luck on this yet?

Comment: @Brian After 2 days of struggling, I've set up windows 7 vm and installed vs 2013 on it :)

Comment: Struggling with this error. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: @SixOThree if u have some urgent task u have to do, don't waste ur time, VMware+windows7+vs2013 are ur saviors....